# Different default hash values

Tags: ruby

When I create a hash as follows:

```
creatures = { "weasels" => 0,
  "puppies" => 6
}
```

and access a key that is not present in the hash, I get `nil` as the output:

```
puts creatures["tigers"]
```

But when I create a hash with a default value:

```
my_hash = Hash.new("hello")
```

and access a key that is not present in the hash, I get `hello` as the result:

```
puts my_hash["hey"]
```

Why am I getting different results in the two cases when I define hashes differently?

Comment: "by giving it a default value" - that's why. What result did you expect?

Comment: "Wha am I getting different results when I am defining a hash differently?" ... That's why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an expected behavior. According to the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html)

> Hashes have a default value that is returned when accessing keys that
>   do not exist in the hash. If no default is set nil is used. You can
>   set the default value by sending it as an argument to ::new:

If you want the hash return `nil` if the key is not present, then do not pass "hello" to  `#new`.